# Use a jSlider to change the volume of audio output in Java

Tags: java, audio, mp3, volume

I already have a class that controls the MP3(play/pause/stop ...etc)

Is it possible to control the volume with javax.sound.*? Or would I have to put in a volume control method in the class that controls MP3?

Comment: Otherwise use JMF package,from that u can control volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this Link:http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/javazoom/jlGui/BasicPlayer.java.html